# Handling extremely small numbers

Tags: r

I need to find a way to handle extremely small numbers in R, particularly in order to take the log of extremely small numbers. According to the R-manual, “on a typical R platform the smallest positive double is about 5e-324.” Well, I need to deal with numbers even smaller (at least as small as 10^-350). If R is incapable of doing this, I was wondering if there is a way I can use a program that can do this (such as Matlab or Mathematica) from R.

Specifically, I am computing a matrix of probabilities, and some of these probabilities are so small that R does not distinguish them from 0. The reason I know this is because each probability is the product of two other probabilities; so I’ll have p(x)=10^-300, p(y)=10^-50, and then p(x)*p(y)=0. I’d like to be able to do these computations, take the log of the resultant very small number (-805.905 for my example, according to Mathematica), and then continue working with the log values in R.

So to be more detailed, I have a matrix of values for p(x), a matrix of values for p(y), both computed using dnorm, and I’m computing the product. In many cases, R is capable of evaluating p(x) and p(y), but the p(x)*p(y) is too small. In a few cases, though, even the p(x) or p(y) value itself is too small, and is itself just equated to 0 in R.

I’ve seen that there is stuff out there for calling R from Mathematica, but not much pertaining to calling Mathematica from R. I’d honestly prefer to do the latter than the former here. So if any one either knows how to do this (either employing Mathematica or Matlab or something else in R) or has another solution to this issue, I’d greatly appreciate it.

Note that I realize there are a few other threads on this topic, discussing such things as using the Brobdingnag package to deal with small numbers, but these do not appear applicable here.

Comment: Can you make use of log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b)?

Comment: For cases where both p(x) and p(y) are individually large enough for R to handle, yes. But unfortunately, sometimes the p(x) or p(y) values themselves are too small (~10^-350), so the log can't be taken (or it is -Inf).

Comment: @user3593717 The distribution functions have a `log.p` parameter.

Comment: Thanks Roland, I had assumed the log option would just give -Inf for the values dnorm gave as 0, but it actually worked.

Comment: @Roland do you mind to expand it in an answer, showing for instance how using `dnorm` (or any other distribution function) with the `log` parameter allows to handle very small numbers? This could be of general interest.

Comment: Use `Rmpfr` or `gmp` ?